# Why doesn't a prefect task fail, if a contained dask.distributed task fails?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, prefect, dask-ml

I'm running a workflow using [Prefect](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect) using a `DaskTaskRunner`, which creates and holds a `dask.distibuted.LocalCluster` instance.
Inside a prefect task I use a `dask_ml.RandomSearchCV` and fit it, which by my understanding should happen using the `LocalCluster`.

When the fitting fails for any reason (i.e. the dask-task submitted to the `LocalCluster` by the `RandomizedSearchCV` fails), the error is printed but it is not propagated to the outer prefect task. The fitting runs (and fails) endlessly.

A minimal example

```py
from distributed import Client
from prefect import task, flow
from prefect_dask import DaskTaskRunner
from dask_ml.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import pandas as pd

@task
def sample_task():
    X = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": ["str", 1, 2], "C": [0, 0, 0]})
    y = X["C"]

    estimator = RandomizedSearchCV(
        estimator=RandomForestRegressor(),
        param_distributions={'max_depth': [3, 5, 7]},
    )

    estimator.fit(X, y)


@flow
def sample_flow():
    sample_task.submit()

    print("This should not be printed")


sample_flow.with_options(
    task_runner=DaskTaskRunner(
        cluster_class="dask.distributed.LocalCluster"
    )
)()
```

As expected, the fitting fails because of the string inside `X`. However I would expect that the prefect task `sample_task()` then also fails, but it doesn't.

Probably a retry limit for the dask task would also do it, but those are submitted by `RandomizedSearchCV`.
Is there any way I can propagate that error, so that my prefect task also fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dask_ml.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV raises a warning and not an error, so Prefect doesn't stop dask-ml from retrying.

You can see the dask-ml code [here](https://github.com/dask/dask-ml/blob/main/dask_ml/model_selection/_search.py#L1278)